# SimpleDateFormat Wrong value in Java

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I'm trying to set a calendar value to it's base (0) to compare it to another value later on. When I tried to print the result I'm getting the month value when using SimpareDateFormat. Any thoughts? and I'm doing it right?

```
SimpleDateFormat DataDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat DataDateFormatMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

Calendar cld = Calendar.getInstance();
cld.set(1, 1, 1);

System.out.println(DataDateFormat.format(cld.getTime()));       //  ->  0001-02-01
System.out.println(DataDateFormatMonth.format(cld.getTime()));  //  ->  02      !!!!
System.out.println(cld.get(Calendar.MONTH));                    //  ->  1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Month interval is 0 to 11 in Calendar API.

```
JAN--->0
.......
DEC--->11
```

**Calendar.MONTH** will return an **int value (2)** which in your case is the value of MM . i.e., **Calander.MONTH is a constant**

breaking down:

```
System.out.println(cld.get(Calendar.MONTH));                    //  ->  1
Calaender.MONTH--- 2
cld.get(2); will get the value at the given calendar field. (in this case 2, your month field whihc is 1)
```

For instance change your last print statement to

```
 Calendar cld = Calendar.getInstance();
 cld.set(10, 10, 1100); (format is MM,dd,YYYY)
 System.out.println(cld.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

the output will be 10(it will return the month value in the format) as **Calendar.YEAR would return 1**.

Answer (score 3):

Month start with 0 in `calander`. JANUARY -> 0, FEBRUARY -> 1... DECEMBER ->11

Answer (score 1):

From the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) of set()
Parameters:

- year - the value used to set the YEAR time field.
- month - the value used to set the MONTH time field. **Month value is
  0-based. e.g., 0 for January.**
- date - the value used to set the DATE time field.

Comment: This makes it especially easy to translate sources from other languages into Java. Cost me some minutes to find out the difference between the literal `4` and `Calendar.APRIL`. Thank you, Oracle. Btw, your link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

That is what you wanted to get as `new SimpleDateFormat("MM")` will format the input date and return you only the `MM` value which is the month.